# Equivalences in omp_places?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, affinity

I'm having some trouble with omp_places and seem to find contradictory information
From http://openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP_Examples_4.0.1.pdf

I find that:

```
omp_places={0:2}:8:2
```

is equivalent to:

```
omp_places="{0,1},{2,3},{4,5},{6,7},{8,9},{10,11},{12,13},{14,15}"
```

In my code I automatically builds a string depending on the amount of cores detected in the system and user specification about numa spreading etc.

When there is no spreading I often end up with the following string:

```
OMP_PLACES={0:16}:1:16
```

which I would assume is equivalent to:

```
OMP_PLACES={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
```

The problem is that the first one throws a warning about threads trying to get bound to ID 16-31 which is outside the range.

I'm guessing my issue is the last 16 in the OMP_PLACES line, but I don't really understand why.

My understanding of what these parameters do are the following:

```
OMP_PLACES={a:b}:c:d

a = first thread ID in a group
b = number of threads to bind in this grouping
c = number of groups to create
d = the shift in first thread ID from one group to the following
```

Now obviously something is wrong with my understanding, so could anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: It could be a bug in the OpenMP runtime parser but without knowing the actual compiler and version one can only make blind guesses (unless one is in possession of a working magical orb, of course). Also, for a place you could simply specify `{0:16}`

Comment: Okay I wasn't aware that this was compiler specific, in that case I should ask this question on the Intel forum I guess.

Comment: The syntax is not supposed to be compiler-specific, but the bugs in the implementation are.

Comment: So you believe my understanding of omp_places is correct, and what I am seeing here is a bug instead?